# Using awk sed or grep to parse URLs from webpage source

Tags: regex, scripting, sed, awk, grep

I am trying to parse the source of a downloaded web-page in order to obtain the link listing. A one-liner would work fine. Here's what I've tried thus far:

This seems to leave out parts of the URL from some of the page names.

```
$ cat file.html | grep -o -E '\b(([\w-]+://?|domain[.]org)[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))'|sort -ut/ -k3
```

This gets all of the URL's but I do not want to include links that have/are anchor links. Also I want to be able to specify the domain.org/folder/:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{
RS="</a>"
IGNORECASE=1
}
{
  for(o=1;o<=NF;o++){
    if ( $o ~ /href/){
      gsub(/.*href=\042/,"",$o)
      gsub(/\042.*/,"",$o)
      print $(o)
    }
  }
}' file.html
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: `grep -E` doesn't understand non-capturing sub-patterns or `\w` escapes inside character classes. You need to use `grep -P`.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: now that returns similar results to the second example but I need to be able to weed out the anchor links and specify a http://domain.com/folder

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are only parsing something like < a > tags, you could just match the href attribute like this:

```
$ cat file.html | grep -o -E 'href="([^"#]+)"' | cut -d'"' -f2 | sort | uniq
```

That will ignore the anchor and also guarantee that you have uniques.  This does assume that the page has well-formed (X)HTML, but you could pass it through Tidy first.

Comment: that works similar to the second example that I posted but I'm looking for a way to trim the results that are anchor links.

http://domain.com/folder/link.html
http://domain.com/folder/link.html#anchor **not desirable**

Comment: great, but now it seems to be including other links (maybe I just didn't notice them before. Can the grep statement also specify the domain.com/folder/? Thanks

Comment: @Astron, sure add ` | grep 'domain.cold/folder/'` at the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

```
lynx -dump http://www.ibm.com
```

And look for the string 'References' in the output. Post-process with `sed` if you need to.

Using a different tool sometimes makes the job simpler. Once in a while, a different tool makes the job dead simple.  This is one of those times.