# How to reorganize and rename files within project without breaking all connections/links?

Tags: project, code-organization, file-rename, batch-rename

I have general web project including images, scripts and styles and I would like to reorganize entire project without breaking it.

- Change folder structure
- Change file names

and keep all links/connections working.

*// I am using Sublime 2 text editor and GIT*

Any ide?

Comment: What technology do you use? E.g. Eclipse can do that kind of refactoring for Java.

Comment: [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) as editor. Javascript: Foundation 3, hammer.js, node.js, jQuery. I do not compile anything, just need keep all links working.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on Linux (or Mac) you could use Awk, Grep or Sed to do the work.

Comment: There are some examples on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369249/using-awk-sed-or-grep-to-parse-urls-from-webpage-source